# How to associate two lists or columns?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multiple-columns

**Code/Program:**

```
    # 1. Represent all unique feature types (column 2).

    lines = f.read().split('\n')

    # Set features

    unique_features = set((i.split('\t')[1]) for i in lines)
    unique_features = sorted(unique_features)
    qty_features = [str(i.split('\t')[1]) for i in lines]

for feature in unique_features:
    print(feature, qty_features.count(feature))


# 2. For every feature type (column 2) it stores all feature names (column 4) that had that type.

# Create a list of types and names

types = list(unique_features)
names = list([str(i.split('\t')[3]) for i in lines])

data = dict()

for i in range(len(types)):
    data[types[i]] = names[i]

print(data)
```

**I have the problem in the code that is after the comment:**

`"# 2. Demonstrate the use of a data structure that associates the feature names to feature types".`

I am trying to get the data in column # 4 of the file that is associated to column # 2.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

For each Feature Type (column 2), I would like to get all the Feature Names (column 4) that are associated with the Feature Types.

```
{'ORF': ['YAL069W', 'YAL068W-A', 'YAL068C', 'YAL067W-A' ... ] }
{'CDS': ['YAL068W-A', 'YAL068C', 'YAL067W-A', 'YAL067C' ... ] }
```

And that with all the unique values in column 2:

```
(ARS
ARS_consensus_sequence
CDS
LTR_retrotransposon
ORF
W_region
X_element
X_element_combinatorial_repeat
X_region
Y_prime_element
Y_region
Z1_region
...
etc etc)
```

That every value of column 4 that belongs to them, is stored in them, like classifying them...

**And what I'm getting with the code is**

```
{'ARS': 'YAL069W', 'ARS_consensus_sequence': '', 'CDS': 'YAL068W-A', 'LTR_retrotransposon': '', 'ORF': 'ARS102', 'W_region': 'TEL01L', 'X_element': '', 'X_element_combinatorial_repeat': '', 'X_region': '', 'Y_prime_element': 'YAL068C', 'Y_region': '', 'Z1_region': 'YAL067W-A', 'Z2_region': '', 'blocked_reading_frame': 'ARS103', 'centromere': 'YAL067C', 'centromere_DNA_Element_I': '', 'centromere_DNA_Element_II': 'YAL066W', 'centromere_DNA_Element_III': '', 'external_transcribed_spacer_region': 'YAL065C', 'five_prime_UTR_intron': '', 'gene_group': 'YAL064W-B', 'intein_encoding_region': '', 'internal_transcribed_spacer_region': 'YAL064C-A', 'intron': '', 'long_terminal_repeat': 'YAL064W', 'mating_type_region': '', 'matrix_attachment_site': 'YALWdelta1', 'ncRNA_gene': 'YAL063C-A', 'non_transcribed_region': '', 'noncoding_exon': 'YAL063C', 'not in systematic sequence of S288C': '', 'not physically mapped': 'ARS104', 'origin_of_replication': '', 'plus_1_translational_frameshift': 'YAL062W', 'pseudogene': '', 'rRNA_gene': 'YAL061W', 'silent_mating_type_cassette_array': '', 'snRNA_gene': 'YAL060W', 'snoRNA_gene': '', 'tRNA_gene': 'YAL059W', 'telomerase_RNA_gene': '', 'telomere': 'YAL059C-A', 'telomeric_repeat': '', 'transposable_element_gene': 'YAL058W'}
```

In that output, what it is printing are the 'unique_features' that are already set, but with the Feature Names that do not correspond to it, it is not even printing them all.

EG. FILE:

```
S000036595  noncoding_exon                  snR18       1   142367  142468  W       2011-02-03  2000-05-19|2007-05-08   
S000000002  ORF Verified    YAL002W VPS8    CORVET complex membrane-binding subunit VPS8|VPL8|VPT8|FUN15    chromosome 1    L000003013  1   143707  147531  W       2011-02-03  2004-01-14|1996-07-31   Membrane-binding component of the CORVET complex; involved in endosomal vesicle tethering and fusion in the endosome to vacuole protein targeting pathway; interacts with Vps21p; contains RING finger motif
S000031737  CDS                 YAL002W     1   143707  147531  W       2011-02-03  2004-01-14|1996-07-31   
S000121255  ARS     ARS108      ARSI-147    chromosome 1        1   147398  147717          2014-11-18  2014-11-18|2007-03-07   Autonomously Replicating Sequence
S000000001  ORF Verified    YAL001C TFC3    transcription factor TFIIIC subunit TFC3|tau 138|TSV115|FUN24   chromosome 1    L000000641|L000002287   1   151166  147594  C   -1  2011-02-03  1996-07-31  Subunit of RNA polymerase III transcription initiation factor complex; part of the TauB domain of TFIIIC that binds DNA at the BoxB promoter sites of tRNA and similar genes; cooperates with Tfc6p in DNA binding; largest of six subunits of the RNA polymerase III transcription initiation factor complex (TFIIIC)
S000030735  CDS                 YAL001C     1   151006  147594  C       2011-02-03  1996-07-31  
S000030734  CDS                 YAL001C     1   151166  151097  C       2011-02-03  1996-07-31  
S000030736  intron                  YAL001C     1   151096  151007  C       2011-02-03  1996-07-31
```

Comment: Just in case, the link of the file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbpDzYdJz2vHgyduJdUr_SyIRomymHhB/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat inefficient in the sense that it repeatedly splits the all the lines up.  In the code below, this is only done once when they are first read in from the file. In addition, after reading they're transposed into columns of row since most of the processing is done with respect to what in each column.

```
from pprint import pprint, pp

NUMCOLS = 4  # Number columns of interest.
filepath = 'SGD_features.tab'

# Retrieve only number of columns needed from each row of data.
with open(filepath) as file:
    rows = [row.split('\t', NUMCOLS)[:NUMCOLS] for row in file.read().splitlines()]

cols = list(zip(*rows))  # Transpose rows and columns for further processing.
unique_features = sorted(set(cols[1]))

print('Quantities of each unique feature')
qty_features = cols[1]
for feature in unique_features:
    print(f'  {qty_features.count(feature)} - {feature}')

feature_dict = {key: [] for key in unique_features}  # Initialize to empty lists.
for col1, col3 in zip(cols[1], cols[3]):
    if col3:
        feature_dict[col1].append(col3)

print()
print('Feature dictionary')
pp(feature_dict, indent=1)
```

Output from processing the first 15 lines of that `SGD_features.tab` file you provided a link to in a comment *under* your question (**not** the sample data shown in it):

```
Quantities of each unique feature
  2 - ARS
  4 - CDS
  5 - ORF
  1 - X_element
  1 - X_element_combinatorial_repeat
  1 - telomere
  1 - telomeric_repeat

Feature dictionary
{'ARS': ['ARS102', 'ARS103'],
 'CDS': [],
 'ORF': ['YAL069W', 'YAL068W-A', 'YAL068C', 'YAL067W-A', 'YAL067C'],
 'X_element': [],
 'X_element_combinatorial_repeat': [],
 'telomere': ['TEL01L'],
 'telomeric_repeat': []}
```